# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.(I)V at org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme.(BasicScheme.java:65)

Tags: java, post, glassfish, httpclient, apache-commons

This is occurring even though I'm not using Base64.

I do have commons-codec-1.9 referenced and in the lib directory of my domain in Glassfish, and the code that causes the error is also referenced in httpclient-4.3.4 and in the lib directory.

```
    try {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
        {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("myusername", "mypassword".toCharArray());
            }
        });

        String xmlRequestString = formatXMLRequest((Exception) exception);

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://mysite.org/post.xml");

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlRequestString);
        entity.setContentType("text/xml");

        post.setEntity(entity);

        client.execute(post); // <--- HERE is where the error is thrown
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LogManagerBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This error usually happens when you compile your code with one version of a third party jar in your build path, and run your code with a different version of that jar in your library path.

Comment: Yea, I figured that. I was really careful to ensure it wasn't. I undeployed my ear from Glassfish, stopped glassfish, got rid of an old version in there, put the new version in the lib directory, deleted all the caches, restarted glassfish, and redeployed after building everything. Still stumped.

Comment: But are you using the same version of the jar in your build path?

Comment: No. I'm using Maven and I don't have any particular libs in my command line path. Maven declares the build version. Glassfish domain lib has the run version. They are the same.

Answer (score 3):

The is a binary compatibility issue that is caused by having incompatible libraries your webapp's effective classpath.  Specifically, the JAR file that contains the `BasicScheme` class is incompatible with the JAR file that contains the `Base64` class. The former contains a call to a method that doesn't exist in the version of the latter that the classloader has found.

> This is occurring even though I'm not using Base64.

Yes.  But the `BasicScheme` class >>is<<, and *something* using that class.

---

The signature `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.(I)V` is referring to a constructor that takes an `int` argument.  According to GrepCode, all versions of Apache Commons Codec since version 1.4 have this constructor.  But version 1.3 does not.  So look in your appserver for an old copy of the "commons-codec" JAR file.

Note that if a webapp (or whatever) has multiple versions of a library in its classpath, then the version that is in the JAR file that is earlier in the classpath *wins*.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have conflict with `commons-codes` library. for example you have both library 1.2 and 1.9 exists together in your classpath, error signature that has been occurred, related to class constructor overloading in different versions

Answer (score 0):

For me it resolved when I removed the jar(documentum jar) from classpath, which had inturn has codec within it which was the older version of it. So probably look into your classpath and try to find if you have any conflicts, which is overriding your codec-1.9